# ffmpeg fails to mux video and audio properly

Tags: ffmpeg

So I have this recorded video file transcoded by `avidemux`. For some reason the audio turned out to be crap. Therefore, I used `ffmpeg` to generate the audio manually from the original source:

```
G:\My Downloads\converting>ffmpeg -i "20130912 1313 - Sky Cinema HD - Liebe.ts"
-map 0:2 -ss 0:2:16.220 Liebe.m4a
ffmpeg version N-57961-gec8e68c Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov  7 2013 18:01:40 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-l
ibopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aa
cenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavp
ack --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 52.100 / 52. 52.100
  libavcodec     55. 41.100 / 55. 41.100
  libavformat    55. 21.100 / 55. 21.100
  libavdevice    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
  libavfilter     3. 90.102 /  3. 90.102
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[h264 @ 03d78060] non-existing PPS referenced
[h264 @ 03d78060] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 03d78060] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 03d78060] no frame!
[h264 @ 03d78060] non-existing PPS referenced
[h264 @ 03d78060] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 03d78060] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 03d78060] no frame!
[h264 @ 03d78060] non-existing PPS referenced
[h264 @ 03d78060] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 03d78060] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 03d78060] no frame!
[h264 @ 03d78060] non-existing PPS referenced
[h264 @ 03d78060] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 03d78060] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 03d78060] no frame!
[h264 @ 03d78060] non-existing PPS referenced
[h264 @ 03d78060] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 03d78060] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 03d78060] no frame!
[h264 @ 03d78060] non-existing PPS referenced
[h264 @ 03d78060] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 03d78060] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 03d78060] no frame!
[h264 @ 03d78060] non-existing PPS referenced
[h264 @ 03d78060] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 03d78060] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 03d78060] no frame!
[h264 @ 03d78060] non-existing PPS referenced
[h264 @ 03d78060] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 03d78060] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 03d78060] no frame!
[h264 @ 03d78060] mmco: unref short failure
    Last message repeated 3 times
[mpegts @ 03d8d360] PES packet size mismatch
    Last message repeated 2 times
Input #0, mpegts, from '20130912 1313 - Sky Cinema HD - Liebe.ts':
  Duration: 02:21:58.64, start: 87280.793944, bitrate: 6588 kb/s
  Program 118
  Program 129
  Program 130
  Program 131
    Stream #0:0[0x20](deu): Subtitle: dvb_teletext ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:1[0x4ff]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv,
 bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:2[0x503](deu): Audio: ac3 ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006), 48000 Hz, stere
o, fltp, 384 kb/s (clean effects)
    Stream #0:3[0x504](eng): Audio: ac3 ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006), 48000 Hz, stere
o, fltp, 384 kb/s (clean effects)
Output #0, ipod, to 'Liebe.m4a':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.21.100
    Stream #0:0(deu): Audio: aac (libvo_aacenc) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, s
tereo, s16, 128 kb/s (clean effects)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:0 (ac3 -> libvo_aacenc)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Input stream #0:2 frame changed from rate:48000 fmt:fltp ch:2 chl:stereo to rate
:48000 fmt:fltp ch:6 chl:5.1(side)
Input stream #0:2 frame changed from rate:48000 fmt:fltp ch:6 chl:5.1(side) to r
ate:48000 fmt:fltp ch:2 chl:stereo
Input stream #0:2 frame changed from rate:48000 fmt:fltp ch:2 chl:stereo to rate
:48000 fmt:fltp ch:6 chl:5.1(side)
[mpegts @ 03d8d360] PES packet size mismatch8.0kbits/s
[ac3 @ 03da9de0] incomplete frame
size=  132498kB time=02:19:41.47 bitrate= 129.5kbits/s
video:0kB audio:130961kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 1.173612%

[libvo_aacenc @ 0039fae0] 1 frames left in the queue on closing

G:\My Downloads\converting>
```

I have no idea what it means regarding those channel setups in the output file. Anyway, now I have a video file with nice video and bad audio and above audio file with nice audio.

Now I want to mux these two together:

```
G:\My Downloads\converting>ffmpeg -i V:\et9200\Liebe.mp4 -i Liebe.m4a -shortest
-map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c copy "Liebe neu.mp4"
ffmpeg version N-57961-gec8e68c Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov  7 2013 18:01:40 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-l
ibopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aa
cenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavp
ack --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 52.100 / 52. 52.100
  libavcodec     55. 41.100 / 55. 41.100
  libavformat    55. 21.100 / 55. 21.100
  libavdevice    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
  libavfilter     3. 90.102 /  3. 90.102
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'V:\et9200\Liebe.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf54.63.104
  Duration: 02:02:10.76, start: 0.160000, bitrate: 935 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x690
[SAR 1:1 DAR 128:69], 876 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(deu): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 50
 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Liebe.m4a':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4A
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2
    encoder         : Lavf55.0.100
  Duration: 02:19:41.49, start: 0.018667, bitrate: 129 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(deu): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 12
8 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
File 'Liebe neu.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, mp4, to 'Liebe neu.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.21.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1280x690 [S
AR 1:1 DAR 128:69], q=2-31, 876 kb/s, 25 fps, 25k tbn, 25k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(deu): Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, 128
 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  194 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=    3545kB time=00:00:47.27 bitrate= 614.4kbits/
frame= 2286 fps=2280 q=-1.0 size=    7183kB time=00:01:52.61 bitrate= 522.5kbits
frame= 2849 fps=1893 q=-1.0 size=   10467kB time=00:03:16.33 bitrate= 436.7kbits
frame= 3302 fps=1647 q=-1.0 size=   13966kB time=00:04:38.48 bitrate= 410.8kbits
frame= 4006 fps=1596 q=-1.0 size=   17392kB time=00:06:10.66 bitrate= 384.4kbits
frame= 4344 fps=1441 q=-1.0 size=   21651kB time=00:07:42.82 bitrate= 383.2kbits
frame= 4724 fps=1344 q=-1.0 size=   25845kB time=00:09:02.69 bitrate= 390.1kbits
frame= 5162 fps=1286 q=-1.0 size=   29610kB time=00:10:59.43 bitrate= 367.8kbits
frame= 5738 fps=1271 q=-1.0 size=   32903kB time=00:12:33.83 bitrate= 357.6kbits
frame= 6314 fps=1258 q=-1.0 size=   36053kB time=00:14:28.30 bitrate= 340.1kbits
frame= 6960 fps=1261 q=-1.0 size=   38543kB time=00:15:56.56 bitrate= 330.1kbits
frame= 7416 fps=1232 q=-1.0 size=   42456kB time=00:17:06.34 bitrate= 338.9kbits
frame= 7958 fps=1221 q=-1.0 size=   46004kB time=00:18:36.13 bitrate= 337.7kbits
frame= 8558 fps=1218 q=-1.0 size=   48623kB time=00:20:18.51 bitrate= 326.9kbits
frame= 9129 fps=1213 q=-1.0 size=   50806kB time=00:22:07.08 bitrate= 313.6kbits
frame= 9795 fps=1219 q=-1.0 size=   52689kB time=00:24:07.91 bitrate= 298.1kbits
frame=10566 fps=1238 q=-1.0 size=   54654kB time=00:26:06.67 bitrate= 285.8kbits
frame=11528 fps=1276 q=-1.0 size=   56509kB time=00:27:51.14 bitrate= 277.0kbits
frame=11984 fps=1256 q=-1.0 size=   59588kB time=00:31:07.75 bitrate= 261.4kbits
frame=12544 fps=1249 q=-1.0 size=   62894kB time=00:33:08.56 bitrate= 259.1kbits
frame=13089 fps=1242 q=-1.0 size=   66155kB time=00:35:00.13 bitrate= 258.1kbits
frame=13678 fps=1239 q=-1.0 size=   69123kB time=00:37:06.17 bitrate= 254.4kbits
frame=14217 fps=1231 q=-1.0 size=   72360kB time=00:38:40.38 bitrate= 255.5kbits
frame=14792 fps=1228 q=-1.0 size=   75309kB time=00:40:08.44 bitrate= 256.2kbits
frame=15371 fps=1225 q=-1.0 size=   78566kB time=00:41:32.39 bitrate= 258.2kbits
frame=15863 fps=1215 q=-1.0 size=   81622kB time=00:46:06.80 bitrate= 241.7kbits
frame=16406 fps=1210 q=-1.0 size=   85172kB time=00:47:51.10 bitrate= 243.0kbits
frame=16967 fps=1206 q=-1.0 size=   87951kB time=00:49:50.03 bitrate= 241.0kbits
frame=17428 fps=1197 q=-1.0 size=   91644kB time=00:51:22.21 bitrate= 243.6kbits
frame=17980 fps=1193 q=-1.0 size=   95013kB time=00:52:56.42 bitrate= 245.0kbits
frame=18594 fps=1195 q=-1.0 size=   98032kB time=00:54:22.46 bitrate= 246.2kbits
frame=19160 fps=1193 q=-1.0 size=  100684kB time=00:56:25.32 bitrate= 243.6kbits
frame=19672 fps=1187 q=-1.0 size=  103702kB time=00:58:08.55 bitrate= 243.5kbits
frame=20180 fps=1182 q=-1.0 size=  106947kB time=01:00:16.91 bitrate= 242.2kbits
frame=20672 fps=1177 q=-1.0 size=  109839kB time=01:01:55.05 bitrate= 242.2kbits
frame=21227 fps=1175 q=-1.0 size=  113118kB time=01:03:19.01 bitrate= 243.9kbits
frame=21744 fps=1171 q=-1.0 size=  116339kB time=01:05:03.46 bitrate= 244.2kbits
frame=22276 fps=1168 q=-1.0 size=  119746kB time=01:06:37.67 bitrate= 245.4kbits
frame=23006 fps=1175 q=-1.0 size=  122202kB time=01:08:03.69 bitrate= 245.1kbits
frame=23714 fps=1181 q=-1.0 size=  124414kB time=01:09:07.34 bitrate= 245.7kbits
frame=24398 fps=1186 q=-1.0 size=  127110kB time=01:10:35.24 bitrate= 245.9kbits
frame=25050 fps=1189 q=-1.0 size=  129441kB time=01:12:16.46 bitrate= 244.5kbits
frame=25698 fps=1191 q=-1.0 size=  131917kB time=01:13:53.87 bitrate= 243.7kbits
frame=26356 fps=1194 q=-1.0 size=  134314kB time=01:15:42.44 bitrate= 242.2kbits
frame=26946 fps=1193 q=-1.0 size=  136646kB time=01:17:55.56 bitrate= 239.4kbits
frame=27620 fps=1196 q=-1.0 size=  139091kB time=01:19:42.05 bitrate= 238.3kbits
frame=28261 fps=1198 q=-1.0 size=  141598kB time=01:21:44.93 bitrate= 236.5kbits
frame=28872 fps=1198 q=-1.0 size=  144161kB time=01:23:23.24 bitrate= 236.0kbits
frame=29493 fps=1199 q=-1.0 size=  146493kB time=01:25:36.36 bitrate= 233.6kbits
frame=30102 fps=1199 q=-1.0 size=  148991kB time=01:27:31.05 bitrate= 232.4kbits
frame=30696 fps=1199 q=-1.0 size=  151992kB time=01:29:27.80 bitrate= 232.0kbits
frame=31148 fps=1193 q=-1.0 size=  155663kB time=01:30:53.18 bitrate= 233.8kbits
frame=31694 fps=1191 q=-1.0 size=  158824kB time=01:32:11.62 bitrate= 235.2kbits
frame=32310 fps=1192 q=-1.0 size=  161545kB time=01:33:45.83 bitrate= 235.2kbits
frame=32834 fps=1189 q=-1.0 size=  163289kB time=01:35:30.30 bitrate= 233.4kbits
frame=33418 fps=1189 q=-1.0 size=  165524kB time=01:37:20.85 bitrate= 232.2kbits
frame=34024 fps=1189 q=-1.0 size=  168343kB time=01:39:27.85 bitrate= 231.1kbits
frame=34527 fps=1186 q=-1.0 size=  171751kB time=01:40:51.79 bitrate= 232.5kbits
frame=35080 fps=1185 q=-1.0 size=  174862kB time=01:43:33.58 bitrate= 230.5kbits
frame=35683 fps=1185 q=-1.0 size=  177750kB time=01:45:22.15 bitrate= 230.3kbits
frame=36331 fps=1187 q=-1.0 size=  180709kB time=01:47:18.89 bitrate= 229.9kbits
frame=36942 fps=1187 q=-1.0 size=  183323kB time=01:49:03.33 bitrate= 229.5kbits
frame=37562 fps=1188 q=-1.0 size=  185480kB time=01:51:24.67 bitrate= 227.3kbits
frame=38162 fps=1188 q=-1.0 size=  188238kB time=01:53:05.00 bitrate= 227.3kbits
frame=38802 fps=1190 q=-1.0 size=  191043kB time=01:55:11.97 bitrate= 226.4kbits
frame=39450 fps=1191 q=-1.0 size=  193407kB time=01:56:52.33 bitrate= 225.9kbits
frame=40142 fps=1194 q=-1.0 size=  195984kB time=01:59:07.49 bitrate= 224.6kbits
frame=40823 fps=1196 q=-1.0 size=  198363kB time=02:00:54.01 bitrate= 224.0kbits
frame=41458 fps=1197 q=-1.0 size=  200492kB time=02:03:03.01 bitrate= 222.5kbits
frame=42075 fps=1198 q=-1.0 size=  202608kB time=02:04:39.46 bitrate= 221.9kbits
frame=42750 fps=1200 q=-1.0 size=  205037kB time=02:06:29.86 bitrate= 221.3kbits
frame=43306 fps=1199 q=-1.0 size=  207993kB time=02:08:02.02 bitrate= 221.8kbits
frame=43899 fps=1198 q=-1.0 size=  211349kB time=02:09:56.74 bitrate= 222.1kbits
frame=44505 fps=1198 q=-1.0 size=  213649kB time=02:11:41.06 bitrate= 221.5kbits
frame=45063 fps=1197 q=-1.0 size=  216592kB time=02:13:25.64 bitrate= 221.6kbits
frame=45583 fps=1195 q=-1.0 size=  219505kB time=02:15:03.92 bitrate= 221.9kbits
frame=46350 fps=1200 q=-1.0 size=  222467kB time=02:16:40.35 bitrate= 222.2kbits
frame=47310 fps=1209 q=-1.0 size=  224615kB time=02:18:20.53 bitrate= 221.7kbits
frame=47930 fps=1209 q=-1.0 size=  227902kB time=02:19:40.29 bitrate= 222.8kbits
frame=47949 fps=1138 q=-1.0 Lsize=  331635kB time=02:19:41.49 bitrate= 324.1kbit
s/s
video:198060kB audio:130961kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.79
4403%
```

As you can see from the bitrate on the right side something goes wrong. Also note that `-shortest` didn't do anything.

In VLC the video stops having video at 32 minutes, but the audio continues until 2:19:41. Here's what `ffmpeg` has to say about what it has done:

```
G:\My Downloads\converting>ffmpeg -i "Liebe neu.mp4"
ffmpeg version N-57961-gec8e68c Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov  7 2013 18:01:40 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-l
ibopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aa
cenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavp
ack --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 52.100 / 52. 52.100
  libavcodec     55. 41.100 / 55. 41.100
  libavformat    55. 21.100 / 55. 21.100
  libavdevice    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
  libavfilter     3. 90.102 /  3. 90.102
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Liebe neu.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.21.100
  Duration: 02:19:41.51, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 324 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x690
[SAR 1:1 DAR 128:69], 845 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(deu): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 12
7 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
At least one output file must be specified

G:\My Downloads\converting>
```

Note how it claims `bitrate: 324 kb/s` while the video is still listed with 845 kb/s.

*I had a version from March running and updated to the latest and both are doing it wrong.*

Obvious question: what am I doing wrong here? In case it's a timestamp/sync issue: how do I fix that?

Comment: When you are demuxing audio you are already getting errors. The error is `[h264 @ 03d78060] non-existing PPS 0 referenced;
[h264 @ 03d78060] decode_slice_header error;
[h264 @ 03d78060] no frame!` See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005436/errors-when-decode-h-264-frames-using-ffmpeg) discussion.

Comment: Why are you starting at 2:16.220 during demxing? (-ss 0:2:16.220)?

Comment: @Rajib The video is a direct recording from my satellite receiver, which is probably why there don't seem to be any key frames at the beginning and why I can't do anything about it. The actual content starts 2:16 into the video after some commercials, which is why I don't need the stuff at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seriously, I don't know why this solves it, but then again I'm no ffmpeg-pro. Anyway, what I did was I removed the `-shortest` option. Before that I had to add the `-to` option while generating the nice audio:

```
ffmpeg -i "20130912 1313 - Sky Cinema HD - Liebe.ts" -map 0:2 -ss 0:2:16.220 -to 2:04:27.000 Liebe.m4a
```

Now the audio and the video have pretty much the same length, only apart by a few milliseconds. Then muxing without `-shortest` generated a nice video with nice audio:

```
ffmpeg -i V:\et9200\Liebe.mp4 -i Liebe.m4a -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c copy "Liebe neu.mp4"
```